# How to make the scroll event bubbling on a fixed positionned element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have HTML  elements with a `position: fixed` within an second element with an `overflow-y :auto`

When the mouse is over the fixed element the scroll doesn't bubble to it's parent. When moving away, the scroll occurs.

I've reduced the situation to the code below

```css
main {
  /* I am the element that scrolls */
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

main section {
  flex: 1 1 800px;
  max-width: 800px;
}

main nav {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-width: 100px;
}

main nav a {
  /* I am the element that prevent scroll on when hovering */
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <aside>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">left</a>
    </nav>
  </aside>
  <section>
    <p>Could be a long text...</p>
  </section>
  <aside>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">right</a>
    </nav>
  </aside>
</main>
```

You can test it at [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/bifiwutuda/edit?html,css,output) by trying to scroll over the pink element or somewhere else.

Is there a way in CSS or even in JavaScript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using JavaScript you can still handle the `wheel` event and trigger it to the parent element:

```
const fixedElts = document.querySelectorAll('nav a');
const parentElt = document.querySelectorAll('main');
const bubbleFixedScroll = e => {
    if(e.deltaMode){
       parentElt.scrollTop += e.deltaY;
    }
};
fixedElts.forEach( fixedElt => {
  fixedElt.addEventListener('wheel', bubbleFixedScroll) 
});
```

Of course the delta value can be adapted for a smother scrolling. Also some throttling can be added to prevent to much handlers to be executed.

Comment: DeltaY values are not consistent across browsers, and wheel events fire very differently from trackpad swipes vs a mouse wheel. Normalizing the deltaY values between browsers seems to still be a non-tenable task. If someone has a solution, I'd love to see it.

Comment: For completeness, this is about as close of a solution as I've seen, but I haven't verified it myself: https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalize-wheel

Comment: You&#39;re right but the `deltaY` is still more or less in the same range, I was able to achieve an acceptable behavior by debouncing the event and a fixed delta if I remember correctly

Answer (score 3):

Seems Straight forward, `position:fixed` and/or `position:absolute` as you may now takes the element out of the document flow as if it doesn't exists, like it's somewhat just there for visual effects.

`position:absolute` still can bubble the scroll events of it's relative positioned ancestor as we know.

```css
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Take this out to see the effect */
  position: relative;
}

p {
  height: 5000px;
  /* Mimic overflow */
}

.kid {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="kid"></div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

However `position:fixed` is special, because it's relative to the browser window (viewport), it'll  bubble the scroll event of the browser.

```css
body {
  /* Mimic body has scrollbars */
  height: 5000px;
}

.parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Take this out to see the effect */
  position: relative;
}

p {
  /* Mimic overflow */
  height: 5000px;
}

.kid {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="kid"></div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

**Basically you can't make a fixed position element bubble up it's parent scroll event.**

Comment: So the quick answer is no. I'll try something in javascript then.